# Prevent Mouseenter and Mouseleave Firing Within Element Without Using Pointer-Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' to change the visibility of an image when I enter and leave an element. My issue is these events keep firing even  when I'm within the element. Using 'pointer-events = none' works but it turns off another animation I have on the image. Is there a solution to this that either doesn't use pointer-events nor mousenter/leave and allows me to have animations on my image? [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rs_obi/sz2edjq6/5/)

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src=""/>
<div id='box' class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#image {
    position:absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: none;   
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    const height = $('#image').height() / 2;
    const width = $('#image').width() / 2;
    $("#image").css({
        left:e.pageX-width, 
        top:e.pageY-height
    });
});

$('.box').mouseenter(_=> {
    $('#image').show();
});

$('.box').mouseleave(_=> {
    $('#image').hide();
});
```

Comment: Suggest you cache `$('#image')` object reference. No need to search DOM for it 3 times every pixel you move

Comment: Just skip event if the element that fired it is a child of the main element.

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona but the element appearing and disappearing isn't a child of the main element

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this accomplishes what you're looking for - but you could change the `z-index` of the image and the `background` of the parent container, like:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    const height = $('#image').height() / 2;
    const width = $('#image').width() / 2;
    $("#image").css({
        left:e.pageX-width, 
        top:e.pageY-height
    });
});

let entries = 0;
let exits = 0

$('.box').mouseenter(_=> {
    $('#image').show();
    entries += 1;
    document.getElementById("entries").textContent=entries;
});
  
$('.box').mouseleave(_=> {
    $('#image').hide();
    exits += 1;
    document.getElementById("exits").textContent=exits;
});
```

```css
 .box {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: transparent;
}
#image {
    position:absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: none;
    z-index: -1;  
}

#display {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/580/6_r/875806_R.jpg"/>
<div id='box' class="box"></div>
<div id= 'display'>
  <div id= 'entries'>00</div>
  <div id= 'exits'>00</div>
</div>
```

Which will cause the `.box` to always be on top, even though the image is under your cursor.

Comment: It did work but I didn't quite make my code on JSfiddle as it should be, apologies. There's a div containing the image which for some reason makes a big difference. Demo [https://jsfiddle.net/rs_obi/kcyw6eLp/5/].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe setting a value to indicate the current state of the image?

Something like this:

```
var showImage = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    const height = $('#image').height() / 2;
    const width = $('#image').width() / 2;
    $("#image").css({
        left:e.pageX-width, 
        top:e.pageY-height
    });
});

$('.box').mouseenter(_=> {
    if (showImage)
        return;

    showImage = true;
    $('#image').show();
});

$('.box').mouseleave(_=> {
    showImage = false;
    $('#image').hide();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid as both mouseleave() and mouseenter() are continually triggered